# XSLT save node attribute value into variable

Tags: xslt

How can I store attribute value in a variable?

XML example:

```
<sth:mainNode>
    <DocumentVersion id="01">
        <DocumentType>Type1</DocumentType>
        <Stuff>I want this</Stuff>
    </DocumentVersion>
    <DocumentVersion id="02">
        <DocumentType>Type2</DocumentType>
        <Stuff>I dont want this</Stuff>
    </DocumentVersion>
</sth:mainNode>
```

XSL example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            version="1.0" xmlns:xsk="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" media-type="string"/>
    <xsl:variable name="DOCTYPE_KEYWORD" select="'Type1'"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:if test="//DocumentVersion[@id]/DocumentType = $DOCTYPE_KEYWORD">
            <xsl:variable name="docVersionID" select="@id"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="//DocumentVersion[@id=$docVersionID]/Stuff"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Desired output:

```
I want this
```

I have no clue how to do it. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
<xsl:variable name="docVersionID" select="//DocumentVersion[DocumentType = $DOCTYPE_KEYWORD]/@id"/>
```

Instead of

```
<xsl:variable name="docVersionID" select="@id"/>
```

or you can simply use it in `xsl-value-of`

```
    <xsl:if test="//DocumentVersion[@id]/DocumentType = $DOCTYPE_KEYWORD">
        <xsl:value-of select="//DocumentVersion[DocumentType = $DOCTYPE_KEYWORD]/Stuff"/>
    </xsl:if>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I use your first solution because input XML is more complex and I want to do more complex stuff in XSL aswell.

Also I've noticed that if statement is now redundand